# Non Biometric Passport and Albania

Tags: passports, biometric-passports, albania

I am an Indian citizen living in Germany holding a non-biometric passport. I am traveling to Montenegro and plan on making a day trip to Albania overland and return to Montenegro on the same day.

I saw this on the Wizz Air website:

> Non-biometric passports are no longer valid for traveling outside
>   Albania (regardless of expiry date), and will only be accepted for
>   traveling to Albania.

https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/travel-information/travel-documents#/

Does this apply only to Albanian citizens or for any national? I am due to travel this week and I stumbled upon this while checking in for my flight to Montenegro on the Wizz Air website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That text appears in a section headed "Passengers from Albania."  So yes, it applies to Albanian passports only, and therefore to Albanian citizens only.

Enjoy your trip.